# How to multiple the object state in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have an array:

```
const array = [
    {
        name: "Name 1",
        numbers: 3
    },
    {
        name: "Name 2",
        numbers: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Name 3",
        numbers: 3
    }
]
```

I want that every object with numbers value get multiplied by its state.
Want this:

```
    // Expected Output
const array2 = [
    {
        name: "Name 1"
    },
    {
        name: "Name 1"
    },
    {
        name: "Name 1"
    },
    {
        name: "Name 2"
    },
    {
        name: "Name 2"
    },
    {
        name: "Name 3"
    },
    {
        name: "Name 3"
    },
    {
        name: "Name 3"
    }

]
```

Here every object is multiplied by its number value
How can I do that?

Comment: Hint : you can loop through first array and create new array.

Comment: Why not? Loop to the value of numbers for each objects and add the same into the new array

Comment: Can u provide me the code? Please

Comment: post the code which you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```js
const array = [{name: "Name 1",numbers: 3},{name: "Name 2",numbers: 2},{name: "Name 3",numbers: 3}]

const result = array.map(({ name, numbers }) => 
  [...Array(numbers)].map(_ => ({ name }))).flat()

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

for (length of array) and while (something is not 0)

```js
const array = [
    {
        name: "Name 1",
        numbers: 3
    },
    {
        name: "Name 2",
        numbers: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Name 3",
        numbers: 3
    }
]

function splitArray(arr) {
  let newArr = [], number = -1;
  
  for (let item of arr) {
    number = item.numbers;

    while (number--) {
      newArr.push(item.name);
    }
  }
  
  return newArr
}

console.log( splitArray(array) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop array item first and get the numbers and loop the numbers inside.

```
let newArray = [];
      for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        //get item number
        var numberCount = array[i].numbers;
        for(j=0; j<numberCount.length; j++){
            newArray.push(array[i].name);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [
  {
    name: "Name 1",
    numbers: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Name 2",
    numbers: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Name 3",
    numbers: 3
  }
]

const array2 = array.reduce(
  (previousValue, currentValue) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < currentValue.numbers; i++) {
      previousValue.push({ name: currentValue.name });
    }
    return previousValue
  },
  []
)

console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using **Js es6** `.reduce()` ~ [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

I think the readability is better than just `.map()`.

```js
const array = [{ name: "Name 1", numbers: 3 }, { name: "Name 2", numbers: 2 }, { name: "Name 3", numbers: 3 }]

const result = array.reduce((acc, { numbers, name }) => {
    [...Array(numbers)].forEach(o => acc.push({ name }))
    return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`map()` and `for()`:

```js
const array = [
    {
        name: "Name 1",
        numbers: 3
    },
    {
        name: "Name 2",
        numbers: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Name 3",
        numbers: 3
    }
]

const arr = array.map(el => {
  let elAr = []
  for(let i=0; i<el.numbers; i++){
    elAr = [...elAr, {name: el.name}]
  }
  return elAr
})
const result = arr.flat()
console.log(result)
```